# PHP: Get specific elements from MySQL database to show on top of select options list

Tags: php, mysql

I have a select menu on my website which displays all available countries. The countries come from my MySQL table which contains 10 countries, in a random order. I perfectly know how to retrieve all countries from my table and output them in my HTML select menu with PHP.

However, I was wondering what code-wise would be ***the most efficient way*** when I want to pick *two **specific*** *countries* to appear on top of my options list, with the other eight countries to be listed underneath? I would like to use as little sql and php as possible for achieving this goal.

Let's say I have the following table "countries":

```
   id   name
   1    United States
   2    France
   3    Brazil
   4    Puerto Rico
   5    India
   6    Australia
   7    Italy
   8    Denmark
   9    South Africa
   10   Oman
```

I would like to output the countries in a select menu and I want the list to start with Denmark and India (with their ids as option values).

My goal:

```
<select>
   <option value="8">Denmark</option>
   <option value="5">India</option>
   // ... the other eight countries underneath, in no specific order
</select>
```

The basic SQL query for retrieving all countries would be:

```
SELECT id, name FROM countries
```

How do I need to proceed for achieving my goal best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an alphabetical ORDER as followers, you can also use this statement

```
   SELECT id, name 
     FROM countries
     ORDER BY id=8 DESC, id=5 DESC, name ASC
```

Comment: almost perfect. in the resulting array, 'Denmark' and 'India' are the last items. But I want them to be the first array items. How do I achieve that?

Comment: @Max i don't understand you ... this query returns an array Denemark, India, Australia, Brazil, ... and so on ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`FIELD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM countries
ORDER BY FIELD(name,'India','Denmark') DESC
```

or by using `CASE`

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM countries
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = 'Denmark' THEN 0
              WHEN name = 'India' THEN 1
              ELSE 2 END
```